# How can i add cells if condition is met

Tags: excel, addition, nested-if

How can I add cells if condition is met. I'm using condition if cell value is greater than 5 and equal to 10 then show value of Cell C, and if value is greater than 10 and equal to 15 then add values of cell C and D, and if value is greater than 15 then add values of cell C,D and E.?

I need to ask one more thing. Here is the table and i need to calculate the amount based upon the days.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTWcQ.png
cell
For days 8 to 14 cell A shows 10000, for days 15 to 21 cell A shows B+C and after 21 days cell A shows B+C+D. After 35 days with every passing week it should add cell D values additionally. for example after 35 days calculation should be B+C+D+D and so on.

Comment: I take it that you mean "and *less than or* equal to 10". Try: `=IF(AND(C1>5,C1<=10),C1,IF(AND(C1>10,C1<=15),SUM(C1:D1),IF(C1>15,SUM(C1:E1),"")))`. `""` added to return blank if the formula resolves to `FALSE`

Comment: I need to ask one more thing. Here is the table and i need to calculate the amount based upon the days.

Comment: This is a separate question, so create a new post for this. When you do, please also add some more information on what you are trying to do, what you have already tried yourself and why you're not getting the result you expected (See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question,
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users, and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by using nested if statements and also using AND function

you will use the and(statement1,statement2) to compare the values for example: value>5,value<10

use this in the if(condition,ifTrueValue,ifFalseValue)
again if the condition is false, you can add another if statement to check for more results

You can use the following function in the cell you want the result in

```
=IF(AND(B9>5,B9<=10),C9,IF(AND(B9>10,B9<=15),C9+D9,IF(B9>15,C9+D9+E9,0)))
```

[image]

below is the screen shot of the result that i have tested
Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. I need to ask one more thing. Here is the table and i need to calculate the amount based upon the days.